# Upload image to amazon s3 directly from browser - using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have written code for uploading image to amazon s3 using using angular js from browser directly. For that I am using the library aws-sdk.js . I have a function 'upload' in which I assign the credentials and the params, and the file. While uploading , I get the below error

```
 *No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access*.
```

**My CORS configuration**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedOrigin>https://*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <ExposeHeader>x-amz-server-side-encryption</ExposeHeader>
        <ExposeHeader>x-amz-request-id</ExposeHeader>
        <ExposeHeader>x-amz-id-2</ExposeHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

**My controller function**

```
function _upload($files) {
    $scope.file = $files[0];
    $scope.creds = {
        accessKeyId: '...',
        secretAccessKey: '...',
        region: 'us-west-2',
        bucket: 'sabari-test'
    };


    var bucket = new AWS.S3({
        region: 'us-west-2',
        credentials: new AWS.Credentials($scope.creds.accessKeyId, $scope.creds.secretAccessKey)
    });

    if ($scope.file) {
        // Perform File Size Check First
        var fileSize = Math.round(parseInt($scope.file.size));
        if (fileSize > $scope.sizeLimit) {
            console.log('Sorry, your attachment is too big.');
            return false;
        }
        // Prepend Unique String To Prevent Overwrites
        var uniqueFileName = 'hai' + '-' + $scope.file.name;

        var params = {
            Bucket: $scope.creds.bucket,
            Key: uniqueFileName,
            ContentType: $scope.file.type,
            Body: $scope.file,
            ServerSideEncryption: 'AES256'
        };

        bucket.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err.message);
                return false;
            } else {
                // Upload Successfully Finished
                console.log('File Uploaded Successfully');
            }
        })
    } else {
        // No File Selected
        console.log('Please select a file to upload');
    }
}
```

**file in my bucket - made public** - crossdomain.xml

```
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

What is the setting I need to do to get rid of the first said error? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of the error, I had to install cors..

npm install cors

in addition to that, I had a mistake in my region to be set to us-east-1 which was earlier us-west-2